# Regression and Other Stories vs Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models

Tags: regression, mixed-model, references, glmm

Andrew Gelman and Jennifer Hill wrote *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models* back in 2006. Recently in 2020, they published *Regression and Other Stories*. Is anyone familiar with both and could give some insight on how these two books differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models* is often considered a canonical source regarding many topics on mixed models (aka HLMs,GLMMs,LMMs,etc.). *Regression and Other Stories* is more focused on regression in general. There is a short section on multilevel models in the latter book, but it has a fairly limited scope compared to the older book. So if you are focused on learning about mixed models, I think the older book is better. If you are wanting a comprehensive book on regression in general, than the newer book is better.

One final note is that the previous book is also quite a bit older, and so some of the code/packages don't really work as well as they did in the past. The more recent book obviously has less dated code so it is helpful in that respect as well.

Comment: Andrew Gelman has said on his blog that the plan is to update *Data Analysis....* by splitting it into two books. So *Regression and Other Stories* is the first of those: [Applied regression and multilevel modeling books using Stan](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2015/06/11/applied-regression-and-multilevel-modeling-books-using-stan/)

Comment: Wow that would be great. I really liked the updated regression book and his writing style in general. Look forward to the updated HLM book.